# How to configure the connection string to a remotely hosted MySQL server via UNIX socket, to use in Excel VBA?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, sockets, odbc

I have a working connection string for an older MySQL database server (via TCP/IP), that I am able to successfully use in my Excel VBA code and it works:

```
MySQLConnection.ConnectionString = _
"Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=[IP ADDRESS];Database=[DATABASE NAME];User=[USERNAME];Password=[PASSWORD];"
```

However, I'm having trouble configuring the right connection string to a new MySQL database (via UNIX socket), which is on a shared web-hosting server. Here are the Database server details that I see on the PhpMyAdmin for this new MySQL server:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 5.7.34-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: [***MyUserName***]@localhost
Server charset: cp1252 West European (latin1)
```

I referenced https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/ to try various configurations of the suggested connection strings:
(please note the [HOSTNAME] is the value I fetched by querying on the 'Variables' section of PhpMyAdmin)

```
MySQLConnection.ConnectionString = _
"Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=[HOSTNAME];Database=[DATABASE NAME];User=[USERNAME];Password=[PASSWORD];Protocol=socket;"

MySQLConnection.ConnectionString = _
"Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=[HOSTNAME];Database=[DATABASE NAME];User=[USERNAME];Password=[PASSWORD];Protocol=unix;"

MySQLConnection.ConnectionString = _
"Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=[HOSTNAME]:/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock;Database=[DATABASE NAME];User=[USERNAME];Password=[PASSWORD];Protocol=unix;"

MySQLConnection.ConnectionString = _
"Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=[HOSTNAME];Socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock;Database=[DATABASE NAME];User=[USERNAME];Password=[PASSWORD];Protocol=unix;"
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

I'm sure I'm missing something critical, and I can't figure out what it is. I'm wondering if I am getting the details of the [HOSTNAME] and [SOCKET] correct. I even tried to replace the [HOSTNAME] with an IP address that I found in the remote MySQL option of the cPanel (although I'm not sure that is the right IP Address). Even that doesn't help.

Could you please point me where I am getting this wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to connect Excel (on Windows) to a Unix socket on a different machine? Unix sockets are created in the filesystem on the Unix machine - they're not available over the network. You will have to connect over TCP/IP.

Comment: Did you try the old connection string with the new parameters ? Use the odbc data source manager to test connect.

Comment: @Henrik you got that right! I am trying to connect to MySQL remotely from a Windows machine. Oh I see, I didn't know that - thanks for that information! I'd love to go with the TCP/IP protocol, but how do I get the corresponding details from PhpMyAdmin? I don't seem to find them anywhere - all I see is the list of server details I've provided in the question. Or I might be looking in the wrong place entirely.

Comment: Since it's a shared web-hosting server, it's probably configured to only allow MySQL connections from the same machine (for web applications running on the server), so in that case you won't be able to connect to it directly from Excel. You can try the old connection string with the new IP address and login, as @CDP1802 suggested.

The right solution is probably to create a web app, running on the web server, which connects to the database and exposes a web API that serves the data to Excel as JSON.

Comment: Are you able to say who the hosting company is ?

Comment: Thanks for that explanation @Henrik - makes sense. As CDP1802 suggested, I did try the old connection string with the new IP address and login, it gives me the same error as before.

Comment: @CDP1802 - the hosting company is Crazy Domains (https://www.crazydomains.in/)

Comment: Usually hosting companies have pretty good help pages but they are not always easy to find [see item 10](https://www.crazydomains.in/help/how-to-manage-mysql-database/) and [here](https://www.crazydomains.in/help/how-to-check-mysql-with-telnet/)

Comment: It turns out that for the connection to work I needed to add my IP address to the list of hosts on the "Remote MySQL" option of the cPanel. I did just that, and it started working as expected.